# Communicate between a C++ plugin and a Python program

Tags: python, sockets, visual-c++, binding, zeromq

I'm having so many doubts about this that i thought i should ask. Here's the situation:

I'm writing a C++ .dll that is going to be loaded into a program,"EuroScope.exe". While loaded, the program will give data to the dll which will be constantly sending and receiving data to/from a previously built python program. After receveiving and accepting the data, the dll will transmit it to the running application

I was trying the sockets solution with ZeroMQ that everyone talked so greatly about. Thing is, it's been 2 weeks now and i can't put it to work in VS2012. I tried everything, even opening a thread here,in their homesite,in the mailing list...no one knows how to solve it

So, besides ZeroMQ what do you think is the best option in my case? I already searched and read a lot of them out there (protocol buffers i don't like, it's too complicated for what i want to do i think)

1 more thing. Is binding Python/C++ (e.g. with SIP or ctypes) a valid solution or it doens't serve my purposes? I've read some SIP and ctypes documentation and it seems like what i want...but at the same time i think: what's the purpose of having a C++ program accessible to Python if it's the loaded dll that needs to send data to Python?? I don't know,i'm just overwhelmed with so many information

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Are you able to modify the pre-existing Python application, or are you restricted to communicating with it via ZeroMQ only?  If you are unable to change the Python application's protocol, then you are probably limited to its pre-existing form of communication (sockets or ZeroMQ, etc).  If you are able to modify the Python application, it may be easiest to implement a simple line-oriented socket server that reads a request string until it finds '\n', processes the message, and responds with string that ends with '\n'.  ZeroMQ may be overkill if you only need simple synchronous send/receive

Comment: I don't know cause it's somebody elses thesis, but i think probably not. What i can and most probably going to do is a py program that interacts with the previously made thesis .py's. So what do you suggest, simple sockets (since ZeroMQ is not working)?

Comment: I posted a possible answer, let me know if this is headed in the right direction.  If not, I can revise & add more detail as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simplest approaches is to write a simple Python socket server that does the following:

1. listens on a known port and accepts a TCP connection
2. reads a string until it finds a '\n'
3. splits the line on some delimiter such as ',' or space such as flds = line.split(',')
4. interprets the first field (flds[0]) as a keyword and the remaining fields as parameters to call a function in the underlying python program
5. sends a response string that ends with a '\n'
6. continues to loop over steps 2 through 5 until the socket connection is closed or some sort of "CLOSE" command is received.

The client for this type of server could be written in C++ or in Python and would:

1. connect to the TCP socket on the known port
2. send single-line commands that end with '\n'
3. reads a response string until it finds a '\n'
4. repeats the above process until the desired task is finished or socket connection is closed

I use this approach frequently when I need a simple point-to-point synchronous send/receive protocol implementation.  It is much less heavy-weight than ZeroMQ or other message queueing approaches.

If you need asynchronous communication or have multiple server threads running, then you would want to look into something like ZeroMQ possibly.  But it sounds like your needs are much simpler in this case if I understand correctly.

Using strings is a little slower over the wire than sending binary data, but the protocol is much easier to debug in my experience because you don't have to worry about differences in sizes & byte ordering of binary types (int, long, short, float, double) across different platforms.  And you don't have to dump the packets to a file and look at them in a HEX editor to tell what is being sent over the wire.  Just log the text strings and it is easy to see what is going on.

Python has excellent [TCP socket server and client](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) library support in standard library, and and the .NET library has [good TcpClient support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) which will work well if you decide to write the client with C# or decide to use managed C++.

If you are going to write more traditional C++ (unmanaged) then you should be able to find numerous examples of Win32 sockets programming such as [this site with working TCP client & server Win32 socket code examples and online book](http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/winsock.html).

Comment: I liked it! Thank you very much for the answer, i'm gonna try to implement it today. I'll let you know if i have any more doubt about this

Comment: I'm gonna try and follow [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11843/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-II) tutorial. Do you think i'm going in the right diretion?

Comment: i've been trying the socket and thinking about it and i realized that i need to embed python in c++ because what i'm doing is a plugin that basically is loaded into a program and the plugin does all the necessary stuff. So it makes sense that the python programs don't need to be open and running on python shell right? What do you think?

Comment: The "TCP/IP sockets for embedding" part of the article link you provided is very similar to the approach I was recommending.  Technically having a C++ socket client communicating with a python TCP socket server is not really embedding, it is more like point-to-point client/server implementation.  Terminology aside, I think you would want to start the python process with TCP socket server & connect with C++ TCP socket client.  You could launch the python server process from C++ if you don't want to have it open & running ahead of time.  Hopefully I have understood what you are asking.

Comment: i decided i should go with Embedding Python in C++. I already tested it and it's exactly what i want. Thank you very much for the help and for indicating me in the right direction linguanerd